# Finding set of values of P for which f(x)=p has no real roots

Tags: functions

I'm not much into Algebra and Functions so I got confused in this one. The question ( I'll write it exactly how it asks ) says,

> The function f is defined by $f : x  \to 2x^2 -6x + 5$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Find the set of values of P for which the equation $f(x) = p$ has no real roots.

Please provide answers in simple forms. And Please provide it as soon as you can. I have exams after a few days and I don't have concept on this one. 
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: If you do not want to use discriminant, you can find the y-value of the global minimum of the function. Any P value less than that will make it so that $f(x)=P$ has no real roots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And if you don't want to use the discriminant, you can *complete the square* of the expression $f(x)-p$:
$$
\begin{align}
f(x)-p&=2(x^2-3x)+5-p\\
&=\textstyle 2(x^2-3x+\frac94)-\frac92 + 5-p\\
&=\textstyle 2(x-\frac32)^2+\frac12-p\tag{*}
\end{align}
$$
The equation $f(x)=p$ has no real root if and only if the expression (*) is strictly positive for every $x$. Since $(x-\frac32)^2\ge0$, this occurs precisely when $\frac12-p>0$.

Comment: Thanks for one more idea on doing this. You rock!

Answer (score 3):

the equation $f(x)=2x^2 -6x + 5=p$ leads to a second order equation $2x^2 -6x + 5-p=0$. This equation has no real solutions when the discriminant is smaller than zero (if $ax^2+bx+c=0$, the discriminant is $b^2-4ac$).

Comment: Did you mean $2x^2 - 6x + 5 - p = 0$?

Comment: Yes! thank you for the correction! :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It really helped me. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The Question has been Answered. Thanks to the guys who put their time and effort to solve this question and help me and others out! Thank you guys!